# cannot convert from 'WCHAR' to 'WCHAR [260]'

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++

I am trying to modify the amcap, an application from Windows SDK's example to capture video from UVC webcam having resolution 1600x1200px.

I am trying to hardcode some variables here like filename, default resolution, type of format etc.

```
WCHAR wszCaptureFile[260]; 

gcap.wszCaptureFile = (WCHAR)"Capture.avi\0"    //modified
```

gettnig error:

> 1>.\amcap.cpp(3887) : error C2440: '='
>   : cannot convert from 'WCHAR' to
>   'WCHAR [260]'

What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a literal wide string and use the secure copy function:

```
wcscpy_s(gcap.wszCaptureFile, L"Capture.avi");
```

The literal string provides the terminating zero bytes.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign the array wszCaptureFile with = (as you have done). You can use the copy methods like [strcpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663(VS.80).aspx).

> wcscpy and _mbscpy are wide-character
>   and multibyte-character versions of
>   strcpy

ex:

wcscpy( gcap.wszCaptureFile, L"Capture.avi");

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED based on comments to the answer... and consider wstrcpy_s too.

```
wstrcpy ( wszCaptureFile, L"Capture.avi" );
```

Comment: ... and wstrcpy_s(...) is the safe implementation.

Comment: He also need to use L prefix:

wstrcpy ( wszCaptureFile, L"Capture.avi" );

Comment: Daniel is correct the safe version is better, but a little more complicated given his experience with C, the simple version is better for now.

Comment: The secure version is no more complicated - there is no need to provide a size parameter when the target is an array

Answer (score -4):

Your casting your string to a WCHAR element not a WCHAR array as you are hoping.
Try:

```
wszCaptureFile = L"Capture.avi\0";
```